# Query servlet context at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I create servlets in `ServletContextInitializer` dynamically by some simplified configuration and add further data related to that servlet.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = ConformanceProperties.class)
public class Initializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private ConformanceProperties conformanceProperties;

    // ...

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        for (ConformanceProperties.Capability capability : conformanceProperties.getCapabilities()) {
            ProxyServlet proxy = new ProxyServlet();

            ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet(capability.getName(), proxy);
            registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            registration.addMapping(capability.getBase());
            registration.setInitParameter("foo", "bar");
        }
    }
}
```

Later on in a service bean I would like to get that data from the current servlet context if available:

```
@Service
public class FooAdapter implements ResourceService {

    public static Optional<HttpServletRequest> getCurrentHttpRequest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .filter(ServletRequestAttributes.class::isInstance).map(ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast)
                .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public Promise bar() {
        // ...

        HttpServletRequest request = getCurrentHttpRequest().get();

        if (request != null) {
            String foo = request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("foo");
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in the service bean I always get the application context and not the servlet context. Thus `foo` is `null` and not `bar`. How can I get the servlet context in the service bean directly and not the upper application context?

Comment: You don't create a `ServletContext` the servlet container does that for you. What you can do is add properties to the `ServletMapping` aftger registration, which you can then access.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right! I've debuged yesterday the `addServlet`. First I need to change my question and second the way I'm querying the context at runtime seems to be wrong.